# 2-D and 1-D arrays

Tags: java, arrays, short

First of all, here's the code:

```
public class Test{

   public static void main(String args[]){

    short[][] b = new short[4][4];
    short[][] big = new short[2][2];
    short b3 = 8;
    short b2 [][][][] = new short [2][3][2][2];

　　　// insert code here that will allow the code to compile

     }

}
```

This is a problem from a textbook, here are the two answers that are wrong:

```
b2[0][1][1] = b;
```

The explanation here is that it tries to assign a 2-dimensional array where a 1-dimensional array is expected. Can someone explain this? I do not see where a 1-dimension array is in the code at all.

```
b2[0][2][1] = b[1][0];
```

The explanation for this wrong answer is that it tries to assign a primitive short where a short array is expected. I'm baffled by this one because I don't see a primitive short in this answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in java a multi-dimentional array is actually an array of arrays.

You can think of it as though every time you index the array(that means you put [i] after it) you lose a dimention.

```
b
```

gives a 2-dimentional array,

```
b[i]
```

gives you a 1-dimentional array, and

```
b[i][j]
```

gives you a `short` (which is a primitive)

```
 b2[0][1][1]
```

should also give you a 1 dimentional array, but you're trying to put a 2-dimentional array there, which is the problem.

now for the second wrong answer, `b[i][j]` gives you a primitive., and that's what you're trying to put where the 1-dimentional array should be.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way too look at it is by crossing out the array markers. Think of the initial type as
`b[][][][]`, now when you do `b[0][1][1]` you are effectively "crossing out" the first three [], leaving you with just `b[]` which is an array of shorts. You can apply this to the rest to see why they are wrong.

Trick I use to teach students pointers and arrays that works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the structure of b2 array.

x x x  x x x  x x x  x x x 
x x x  x x x  P[x x]  x x x
x x x  x x x  x x x  x x x

x x x  x x x  x x x  x x x
x x x  x x x  x x x  x x x
x x x  x x x  x x x  x x x

You are trying to get the array at the position of b2[0][1][1] which is a one dimension array having two elements. But, 'b' is two dimension array. So that, it is throwing the error.